# Rails: test module and model conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It was a mistake, but I called some model `Test` (cause it actually a test). Now it is really late to rollback it and give model another name, because this way I need to check a lot of code on changing model name.
Problem. When I call anything about Test in console, it causes error.

```
>> User.last
  #<User id: 44, email: nil, password_digest: nil, created_at: "2013-05-08 11:26:04", updated_at: "2013-05-08 11:26:04", guest: true>

User Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

>> @test=Test.last
NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for Test:Module
    from (irb):7
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/HP/study/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from C:/Users/HP/study/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the model, `rails g migration rename_test`. Then edit the migration like so

```
class RenameTest < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :test, :my_test
  end

 def self.down
    rename_table :my_test, :test
 end
end
```

Comment: yeah, I can, but that means refactoring all code with Test mentioned, and it is not only tests_controller, but other controllers, helpers, models.

Comment: You should do it now than later, I think that is the best approach really.